# PCRE regex for movie data

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i have a string like this

> <14>  south.park.s14e01.locdog.avi [190713856]

i need a php regexp to get an array like this

`array(14, 'south.park.s14e01.locdog.avi', 190713856)`

please help

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_match('/^<(\d+)> \s+ (\S+) \s+ \[(\d+)\]$/x', $input, $your_array);
```

Where your desired results are in `$your_array` starting at index 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = '<14> south.park.s14e01.locdog.avi [190713856]';
preg_match('/<(\d{2})>\s(.+)\s\[(\d{9})\]/',$test,$m);
print_r($m);//[1] => 14 [2] => south.park.s14e01.locdog.avi [3] => 190713856
```